# Finding all order-$2$ elements in the set of $2 \times 2$ matrices with determinant $1$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I have been given a set of $2 \times 2$ matrices, with determinant $1$, Now I have been asked to show that this set forms a group under multiplication (which I have shown) and hence also to find elements of this group with order $2$. This is the part whose solution I want to verify.

My solution:

$$A=
 \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$

Above is a $2 \times 2$ matrix (called $A$) with determinant $1$, i.e. $ad-cb =1$. For any matrix to have order $2$, it must be it's own inverse. The general form of the inverse of this kind of matrices is

$$A^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}.$$

This is true since the determinant is $1$. Now for $A$ to be equal to it's own inverse, we must have $a=d$, $c=-c$, $b=-b$. Therefore we must have $c=0$, $b=0$, and $a=d$.

Now the determinant of $A^{-1}$ must also be $1$ (since $\det(A^{-1})=1/\det(A) =1$); hence $ad=1$, since $a=d$. Therefore we must have $a=+1$ or $a=-1$.

Thus the only elements of the group with order $2$ must be $I$,  or $-I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. That's my proposed solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution so far mostly makes sense, with one caveat.

What you have shown is that, if $A = A^{-1}$ and a unit determinant is forced, then $A= \pm I$.

Is $I$ or $-I$ an element of order $2$ in this set of matrices? Whether they are still needs to be verified.

Remember that the order of an element $g$ is the ***minimum*** $n$ such that $g^n = 1$ (for $1$ the identity of your group $G$).

Comment: What I now realize, is that I and -I both belong to the group, both have unit determinant, but, the order of I is 1, and thus the only such element with order equal to 2, has to be -I. Is that right?

Comment: That's correct.